# Unbale to select form drop down value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, select

I am trying to fill out the form using Python (selenium) ! but facing error **"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"**

Here is my code

```
your_choice=browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//select/option[@value='3']"))
your_choice.click()
```

[image]

I am trying to select the option "automotive" and the value is 3! tried different solution in online but nothing helps !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis in your code as below:

```
your_choice=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select/option[@value='3']")
```

Having said that, you should use [Select Class](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) to perform any actions on a drop-down element.

To click on drop-down option **Automotive**, refer the code below:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "profession_id"))
select.select_by_value("3")

# You can even use the below
# select.select_by_visible_text("Automotive")
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

**NOTE:** Above code will work if selenium can locate just one element with `By.NAME, "profession_id"`, if not you may have to tweak your locator strategy to locate the `<select>` node successfully.

**UPDATE:** Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "profession_id"))))
select.select_by_value("3")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i can able to select Automotive but am unable to click that to move to next form fielsd ! tried something like this "select.select_by_value("3").click()" but not working

Comment: `select_by_value("3")` - This method itself will perform `click()` on the dropdown value. You do not have to click again.

Comment: that means click is not happening! if we click that select option will close but its not closing ! please check SS

Comment: Check the updated answer. Try that code and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you’re encountering, “TypeError: ‘str’ object is not callable”, indicates that you’re trying to call a string as if it were a function. In your code snippet, the issue lies in this line:

```
your_choice=browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//select/option[@value='3']"))
```

The find_element method returns a web element, and you’re attempting to invoke it as a function by adding parentheses after it. However, find_element is a property, not a function. To resolve this, you have a couple of options:

Use the text property:

```
your_choice_text = your_choice.text
```

Use the get_attribute("innerHTML") method:

```
your_choice_text = your_choice.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```